# How to completely remove company portal and intuneMDMAgent from Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft

Yesterday I installed company portal in my personal Mac by mistake. Then my Mac is associated with my company's network. And then I unenrolled my Mac in company portal and removed company portal and profile. But when I restart my Mac, I still can see this screen in login as below. It is really annoying. How could I completely remove this app and its service?

[image]

And I try to disable intune service, still no help.
[image]

Comment: Please don’t use a screenshot of text output. Copy and paste the text into the question with an [edit].

Comment: Wipe the machine, install the OS, restore your backup of your data.